# More efficient SQL statement to eliminate my n^2 algorithm?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

Let's say the following are my SQL tables:

My first table is called `[Customer]`.

```
CustomerID    CustomerName    CustomerAddress
----------    ------------    ---------------
1             Name1           1 Infinity Loop
2             Name2           2 Infinity Loop
3             Name3           3 Infinity Loop
```

My next table is called `[Group]`.

```
GroupID       GroupName
-------       ---------
1             Group1
2             Group2
3             Group3
```

Then, to link the two, I have a table called `[GroupCustomer]`.

```
GroupID    CustomerID
-------    ----------
1          2
1          3
2          1
3          1
```

So on the ASP.NET page, I have two tables I want to display. The first table are essentially all Customers that are in a particular group. So in a drop down list, if I select `Group1`, it would display the following table:

```
CustomerID    CustomerName    CustomerAddress
----------    ------------    ---------------
2             Name2           2 Infinity Loop
3             Name3           3 Infinity Loop
```

The table above is for all customers that are "associated" with the selected group (which in this case is Group1). Then, in the other table, I want it to display this:

```
CustomerID    CustomerName    CustomerAddress
----------    ------------    ---------------
1             Name1           1 Infinity Loop
```

Essentially, for this table, I want it to display all customers that are NOT in the selected group.

To generate the table for all customers that are in the selected group, I wrote the following SQL:

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerID, Customer.CustomerName, Customer.CustomerAddress   
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN GroupCustomer ON
    Customer.CustomerID = GroupCustomer.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Group] ON
    GroupCustomer.GroupID = [Group].GroupID
WHERE [Group].GroupID = @selectedGroupParameter
```

So when I mentioned my n^2 algorithm, I essentially used the SQL statement above, and compared it against a SQL statement where I just `SELECT *` from the `Customer` table. Where there was a match, I just simply had it did not display it. This is incredibly inefficient, and something I'm not proud of.

This leads to my current question, what's the most efficient SQL statement I can write that will eliminate my n^2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to get `Customer`s not in a particular `Group`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM GroupCustomer
        WHERE
            CustomerID = c.CustomerID
            AND GroupID = @selectedGroupParameter
    )
```

Read this [**article**](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) by Aaron Bertrand for different ways to solve this kind of problem and their performance comparisons, with `NOT EXISTS` being the fastest according to his test.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f257dd/4/0)

Comment: Not sure you mean `where c.CustomerID = c.CustomerID`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assistance, and the article from Bertrand!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. You can always rely on Aaron to have an answer on everything sql-server related. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from Customer
where CustomerID not in
  (select CustomerID 
  from GroupCustomer 
  where GroupID = @selectedGroupParameter)
```

You can use `not in` for this check.  That said, you can probably just get rid of the join to the Group table for some increased performance, since you don't appear to actually use the group name.

Comment: Thanks for showing me `not in`. I will keep this in mind. :-)